# Credential request not working in swift

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I ported some objective-c code (with some changes) to swift and the link w/o "private" in it works and the other doesn't. Here"s what I have:

```
import Cocoa

class MasterViewController: NSViewController, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {
  var session: NSURLSession!
  var courses: JSON!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let config: NSURLSessionConfiguration? =
    NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil )
    fetchFeed()
  }

  func fetchFeed() {
    let requestString: String = "https://bookapi.bignerdranch.com/courses.json"
    // let requestString: String = "https://bookapi.bignerdranch.com/private/courses.json"
    if let url: NSURL? = NSURL(string: requestString) {
      let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
      let dataTask : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        var jsonObject: [JSON] = JSON(data: data).arrayValue

        self.courses = JSON(data: data)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { _ in
          println( self.courses?.debugDescription )
        })
      });
      dataTask.resume()
    }
  }

  func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential!) -> Void) {
    var userIdString: String = "BigNerdRanch"
    var passwordString: String = "AchieveNerdvana"
    println( "Received challenge, responding with UID: \(userIdString) PWD: \(passwordString)")
    var cred: NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential(user: userIdString,
      password: passwordString,
      persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)
    completionHandler( NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, cred )
  }

}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: What is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out the URL without "private" in it and uncomment the URL wit "private" in it, it does not work.  If you do it from a web browser (Chrome,Firefox,Safari, etcetera) "https://bookapi.bignerdranch.com/private/courses.json" enter the credentials "BigNerdRanch" for user ID "AchieveNerdvana" for password and it returns the expected JSON

Comment: once again, in the browser, put "https://bookapi.bignerdranch.com/private/courses.json" and enter the credentials, and it works, but I get null in the error.debugDescription text.